# Render 2 table rows in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I want to achieve expandable row functionality for table.
Let's assume we have table with task names and task complexity. When you click on one task the description of task is shown below. I try to do it this way with ReactJS (in render method):

```
  if (selectedTask === task.id) {
    return [
      <tr>
        <td>{task.name}</td>
        <td>{task.complexity}</td>
      </tr>,
      <tr>
        <td colSpan="2">{task.description}</td>
      </tr>
    ];
  } else {
    return <tr>
      <td>{task.name}</td>
      <td>{task.complexity}</td>
    </tr>;
  }
```

And it doesn't work. It says:
`A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object`
I tried also to wrap 2 rows in a div but I get wrong rendering.
Please, suggest correct solution.

Comment: just return the two tr in a string instead of array?

Comment: Actually real life task is a bit more complex. So, string would not be enough

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `render()` method on a React component must **always return a single element**. No exceptions.

In your case, I would suggest wrapping everything inside a `tbody` element. You can have as many of those as you want in a table without disrupting your row structure, and then you'll always return one element inside `render()`.

```
if (selectedTask === task.id) {
    return (
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{task.name}</td>
                <td>{task.complexity}</td>
            </tr>,
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="2">{task.description}</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    );
} else {
    return (
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{task.name}</td>
                <td>{task.complexity}</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could have multiple tbody tags. Good to know.